# Expand accordition menu using url parameters taken by jquery and add attr to desired class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening everyone, i'm having trouble with changing div style attribute. So, i have this code:
Example of URL:  www.example.com"/?page_id=410&ai1ec=action~oneday&post=289

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    console.log(sURLVariables);

    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }

}
```

Down part is for checking and addding style attribute.

```
    var blog = getUrlParameter('post');
console.log(blog);   
    var idx = 1;
    if ($('.ai1ec-event').hasClass('ai1ec-event-id-'+blog)){

    /*$('.ai1ec-event').addClass('ai1ec-expanded');*/
    $('.ai1ec-event-summary').eq(idx).attr('style','display:block');
    idx++;  
    }

});
```

Im using it to expand accordion menu which post number is selected, and so far i have achieved to do it, but it only works for first accordition(i have 3 for now, i;m planning to put more after i fix this).

And there is html code:

```
<div class="ai1ec-date-events">
    <div class="ai1ec-event         ai1ec-event-id-290         ai1ec-event-instance-id-65">

        <div class="ai1ec-event-header"></div>
        <div class="ai1ec-event-summary " style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ai1ec-date-events">
    <div class="ai1ec-event         ai1ec-event-id-289         ai1ec-event-instance-id-66">

        <div class="ai1ec-event-header"></div>
        <div class="ai1ec-event-summary " style="display: block;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ai1ec-date-events">
    <div class="ai1ec-event         ai1ec-event-id-288         ai1ec-event-instance-id-67">

        <div class="ai1ec-event-header"></div>
        <div class="ai1ec-event-summary " style="display: none;">
    </div>
```

So, i need to change ai1ec-event-summary style to display:block; but i can only accomplish that for only one of accorditions. Does anyone have advice how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function to the following:

```
if ($('.ai1ec-event').hasClass('ai1ec-event-id-'+blog)) {
    $('.ai1ec-event-id-'+blog+' .ai1ec-event-summary').attr('style','display:block');
}
```

Since you have the blog id, you don't need to track the index of the panel.

Comment: You misunderstood, i need to change style for single .ai1ec-event-summary. Because thats where content is.

Comment: No problem. Tick the answer as solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

First off you should only have (1) wrapper element and remove class names:

```
<div class="ai1ec-date-events">
    <div class="ai1ec-event" data-id="290" data-instance="65">
        <div class="ai1ec-event-header"></div>
        <div class="ai1ec-event-summary"></div>
    </div>
    ....
    ....
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ai1ec-event-summary {
   display: none;
   margin: 2em 0; /* or whatever */
}
```

jQuery

```
// get the post id
// find the correct accordion with the data attribute
// hide other accordions (in the event that you can open them by clicking something).
// set 'active' class to open accordion
$(function () {
     var postId = getParameterByName('post');
     var $div = $('.ai1ec-date-events').find('.ai1ec-event[data-id="' + postId + '"]').find('div:first');

     if (!$div.hasClass('active')) {
         $div.closest('.ai1ec-date-events')
             .find('.active')
             .removeClass('active')
             .slideUp();

         $div.addClass('active').slideDown();
     }
});


function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```